# List all files ssh; limit to filetype

Tags: ssh

Using SSH, how can I list all files in current directory (`ls`) but limit it to a certain filetype? (.pdf in this case)

so basically

```
ssh user@mydomain.com
cd public_html 
ls (only pdfs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linux `ls` command accepts wildcard filters, try something like `ls *.pdf` to list all pdf's in the current directory.